# HOW TO BUILD A WEB PROJECT INTO MULTIPLE .DLL?

Tags: dll

I have a Web Project that has three Folder(A,B,C) that contains .cs files.
There will be one .DLL Build by VS by default.
but now I want to Build the project into multiple .dll files(A.dll, B.dll,C.dll),
Any one tell me how can I make it?

Answer (score 1):

Separate them into 3 projects A,B & C (still in same solution)
and then add Project Reference to the main Web Project